# Noob attempting js and html coding...and failing miserably

Tags: javascript, html

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" src="mapbody.js"></SCRIPT> 
</head>
<body>

  <A HREF="javascript:a_message()">Click for a message..</A> 

</body>
</html>
```

mapbody.js:

```
function a_message()
{
alert('I came from an external script! Ha, Ha, Ha!!!!');
}
```

When I pull up the web page and click the link nothing happens.  Both files are in the same folder.  What am I missing?

Comment: How dare you use HTML5 doctype with such code??!!!

Comment: I just tried this and it worked for me (using Firefox, if that makes a difference).

Comment: Just tested working in latest Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Your problem is probably around loading the script itself -- where is it located in relation to the html? and how are you loading it?  If you are using chrome, then check the developer-tool-menu / java-script console for hints as to what is going wrong

Comment: @Soren they are both in the same folder.  Is that what you meant by relation to the html.  I'm loading it as a file and a website through firefox.  working on the console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things:

1. HTML-elements should all be lower-case.
2. The `language`-attribute in the `script`-tag is obsolete. Use `type="text/javascript"` instead.
3. A JavaScript-function call should go into the `onclick`-attribute, not the `href`.

A proper implementation might look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Is required!</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapbody.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <a onclick="a_message();" href="#">Click for a message..</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Also, binding function-calls to an HTML-Element using the `onclick` (or any other `onXX`-attribute) is old-school. Library's like jQuery enable you to use CSS-selectors to bind actions on certain HTML-elements, which allows a full separation of HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: I disagree with 3rd, it shouldn't be in html at all.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote since the original code should work.  Doing these things are suggested, but not a solution to the question.

Comment: @Ivan it might work but it's so messy. By telling him "everything works fine here" you are motivating him to keep doing things this way.

Comment: This is weird its still not working fflorents test site below does though

Comment: recreated the file and it seems fine now!  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>...</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" onclick="a_message();">Click for a message..</a> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="mapbody.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Lukas Knuth was faster than me. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (Firefox 8) : http://jsfiddle.net/FCXxU/

Is the URL to your script good?

A simple way to check that is to add an `alert('test');` at the beginning of mapbody.js (before the function).

Comment: what does the alert('test') do?

Comment: just show you a message with "test" printed on it. If the message appears, that means the URL is correct. It is incorrect otherwise.